# Implementing Click In CardView in RecycleView

Tags: android

So I am trying to **make my cards clickable** and as they are clicked it opens a new activity (not implemented in the code below though), here is my code:

**For Interface**

import android.view.View;

```
public interface ClickListener {

    public void itemClicked(View view , int position);

}
```

**For Adapter:**

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.SensorViewHolder> {

    private  ClickListener clicklistener = null;

    List<SensorData> sensors;
    RVAdapter(List<SensorData> sensors) {
        this.sensors = sensors;
    }

    public class SensorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView sensorName;
        TextView sensorDesc;
        ImageView sensorPhoto;
        private LinearLayout main;

        SensorViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            sensorName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sensor_name);
            sensorDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sensor_desc);
            sensorPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sensor_photo);

            main = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main);
            main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Position:" + Integer.toString(getPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(clicklistener != null){
                        clicklistener.itemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener){
        this.clicklistener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public SensorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        SensorViewHolder pvh = new SensorViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SensorViewHolder SensorViewHolder, int i) {
        SensorViewHolder.sensorName.setText(sensors.get(i).name);
        SensorViewHolder.sensorDesc.setText(sensors.get(i).descriptor);
        SensorViewHolder.sensorPhoto.setImageResource(sensors.get(i).iconID);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return sensors.size();
    }
}
```

**and here is the code for MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<SensorData> sensorData;
    private RecyclerView rv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Find the recycler view for the <code>
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);

        //Initialising a linear layout manager
        final LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
        rv.setClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initializeData() {
        sensorData = new ArrayList<>();
        sensorData.add(new SensorData("Accelerometer", "Measures the acceleration of a moving or vibrating body.", R.mipmap.ic_accl));
        sensorData.add(new SensorData("GPS Sensor", "Provides real-time user location and time information.", R.mipmap.ic_gps));
        sensorData.add(new SensorData("Proximity Sensor", "Provides ambient light and proximity sensing.", R.mipmap.ic_als));
    }

    private void initializeAdapter() {
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(sensorData);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**And yet it seems I cannot access `setClickListener`. I must mention I am quite a beginner in this.**

[image: cp]

Where have I mistaken? Is this the correct way to implement clicks on a card or I am missing something?

Also here is the MainActivity XML if needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**and items.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sensor_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sensor_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sensor_photo"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sensor_desc"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sensor_photo"
            android:layout_below="@+id/sensor_name" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**EDIT:** Just to avoid confusion, **I want the use to be able to click the cards and go to a new activity. ** How can I implement that in the simplest possible way? I am really confused on how to do it in the `RecyclerView`.

Thanks a lot and regards.

Comment: You should just implement click listener on the recyclerview which gives you access to the position of the item clicked. Remember, that the old listview differs from recyclerview greatly when it comes to handling click events

Comment: Clicks typically make sense only for parts of the UI which the user can see. `RecyclerView` and `CardView` are containers which are invisible to the user. What do you actually want the user to be able to do here?

Comment: @Eenvincible Yes! It seems I am having tough time to implement clicks in the `RecyclerView`.  Can you use my code to show a small example?

Comment: Try `set**On**ClickListener()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want the use to be able to click the cards and go to a new activity. How can I implement that in the simplest possible way?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I will be really grateful if you can pseudo implement it in my code. Will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a difference between the old `ListView` and the new `RecyclerView` component, I have a reusable piece of code that I use to handle click events (both regular clicks and LongClicks):

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

   @SuppressWarnings("CanBeFinal")
   private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
   @SuppressWarnings("CanBeFinal")
   private OnItemClickListener mListener;

   public interface OnItemClickListener {
      void onItemClick(View view, int position);
      void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);

   }

   public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener)
   {
      mListener = listener;

      mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener()
      {
          @Override
          public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
          {
             return true;
          }

          @Override
          public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)
          {
             View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

             if(childView != null && mListener != null)
             {
                 mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
             }
          }
      });
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e)
   {
      View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

      if(childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e))
      {
         mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
      }

      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent){}

   @Override
   public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

   }
}
```

Then simply do this in your activity or fragment where you want to handle click events:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener
            .OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            //start new activity here
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));
```

That should be the easiest way to do it!

I hope this helps you! Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to set the listener in the Viewholder

```
public class SensorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cv;
    TextView sensorName;
    TextView sensorDesc;
    ImageView sensorPhoto;
    private LinearLayout main;

    SensorViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        //Add the following line below
        cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //The intent firing goes here
            }
        });
        sensorName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sensor_name);
        sensorDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sensor_desc);
        sensorPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.sensor_photo);

        main = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main);
        main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Position:" + Integer.toString(getPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(clicklistener != null){
                    clicklistener.itemClicked(v, getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the compiler error, the correct way to set a `OnClickListener` is with

```
rv.setOnClickListener()
```

Note that the error is because you are missing the word **On**. Generally, you should use autocomplete in Android Studio to help avoid these types of issues. If autocomplete doesn't pop up automatically, you can push Ctrl-Space to get it.

As a side note, you can build your project by clicking `Build -> Make Project` in the main menu. This will give a window with the error messages where you can copy and paste more easily than the usual error balloons.

Comment: I did write a `ClickListener` interface (updated question), should I discard all that?

Comment: @jeet I think you need to read a tutorial about event handling in Android apps. You are missing a few fundamental ideas here. As far as the compiler error is concerned, `RecyclerView` does not have any method named `setClickListener()`. Rather it has an event called `setOnClickListener()`. Notice the word **On**.

Comment: @jeet I'm not sure that this will solve your problem, though, since no matter where you click in the `RecyclerView`, the same action will occur.

Comment: @jeet Also, I don't understand the purpose of `public interface ClickListener`. For event handling, you should use the interfaces already provided in the API rather than create your own.

Answer (score 0):

In your findViewById you are casting the view to a RecyclerView and therefore you are referring the standard RecyclerView implementation of the Android framework. So this would never work.

The next thing is you are trying to set a listener to the RecyclerView but define the setListener method inside your adapter.

So what you should do is to either get a reference to your adapter via:

```
((RvAdapter) rv.getAdapter()).setClickListener();
```

after setting it or even better set the listener before you call

```
rv.setAdapter()
```

via

```
RvAdapter adapter = new RvAdapter();
adapter.setClickListener(listener)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all set tag for your card in onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
holder.cv.setTag(position);
}
```

then add on click listener for your card in your view holder in adapter:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public CardLayout cv;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)  itemView.findViewById(Rid.cv);
        cv.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //for find item that hold in list
        int postition = (Integer) v.getTag();
        ...
    }
```